# Can LDAP be used to authenticate SVN for remote users?

Tags: svn

I'm wondering if SVN (on Apache) can be setup to allow LDAP authentication **remote users**.  I.e. these users are not logged into a domain. Will the SVN client prompt for the domain\user name and then authenticate against a configured Active Directory? (As opposed to just passing along the current users authentication, likely from logging into there local computer.)

**Update**

I am actually more interested in if the svn client will prompt the user for domain credentials if using the currently logged in user fails. I've read about how the server can be setup and as *cjungle* was helpful with.  However, usually, this means that the users are in the correct domain, and they are logged into that domain. My *remote* users won't be. I.e. they will be logged into there local machine (no domain) and will need to provide their domain credentials (domain, user name and password). Is this possible? I.e. Can the (any) svn client support this?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication can be performed on Apache asuming modules `auth_basic`, `authnz_ldap` and `authz_svn` are enabled.

The following configuration works with an OpenLDAP server but should be easyly be made to work with Active Directory.

```
    <Location /r>
            DAV svn
            SVNParentPath /home/svn/repos
            AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/svn/users/access

            AuthType Basic
            AuthBasicProvider ldap
            AuthName "My Company Inc."
            AuthLDAPBindDN "uid=binduser,ou=,ou=systems,dc=company,dc=com"
            AuthLDAPBindPassword "XXXXXXX"
            AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldap.company.com/ou=people,dc=company,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)"
            Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

Authorization is only possible by specifying a file in the `AuthzSVNAccessFile` directive and can't be based on LDAP group membership at least to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, I am more asking about how it works on the client side. The remote users won't be logged into the domain. How does the client handle that? I.e. I assume it would pass in the currently logged in user (which would fail against Active Directory), then would it ask for domain/user and password, and use that to authenticate against Active Directory?